# Hyperlink refers to the new location of the referenced cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I'm using Excel 2003.

I have a hyperlink in cell E4 in `worksheet406R` to cell E4 in `worksheet104S`. When I move E4 in `worksheet104S` to another location (E16) or sort the data in this worksheet, the cell E4 in `worksheet406R` still displays the content of the original linked-to cell, but when I click on it, it goes to cell E4 in `worksheet104S` (which now contains new data), not to the new location (E16) as it should (but still displays its content). How can this be fixed (go to the new location of the linked-to cell).

[image: a link in sheet406R (cell E4) to sheet104S (cell E4)]
[image: the linked cell E4 in sheet 104S]
[image: cell E4 is cut and pasted to cell E16]
[image: when clicking on sheet406R (cell E4) (which displays the text in cell E16) it goes to cell E4, which now contains new data, while it should go to cell E16]

Comment: Are you talking about hyperlinks or cell references?

Comment: It would be better if there could be an example of what is desired. Hyperlinks do not change on their own. If they need to some macro might be required.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Cell E4 in sheet406R contains a hyperlink to cell E4 sheet104S
The later cell was cut and pasted to a new location (E16)
When clicking on cell E4 in sheet406R, it goes to cell E4, which now contains new data, while it should go to cell E16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bill Manville gave me a useful alternative technique in my post
[hyperlink refers to the new location of the referenced cell](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/hyperlink-refers-to-the-new-location-of-the/6f294e89-0e16-4789-a50e-0ba235a24cfd)